# Is "A fault occurred to that system" idiomatic?

Tags: meaning

According to Merriam-Webster, something occurring to someone means an idea about that thing comes to that person's mind. So, it seems one may not say "A fault occurred to that system". So, what is the idiomatic way of saying "that system" experienced a fault?

Comment: "*A fault occurred **in** that system.*"

Comment: @gotube: Thanks. If you write an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"A fault occurred **in** that system" is correct.

The preposition "in" collocates with "fault", so even without any verb, "in" is correct:

> The Fault in our Stars